# Display Custom Taxonomy Name As A Shortcode

Tags: customization, shortcode, taxonomy

On my WordPress site I have created a custom taxonomy named "game" which lists different gaming titles. I want to be able to display the names of these titles on my posts using a shortcode.

Prior to creating a custom taxonomy, I was using WordPress' default categories taxonomy, and had the following code (found on stack exchange) working well:

```
function shortcode_post_category () {
    $html = '';
    $categories = get_the_category();
    foreach( $categories as $category ){
        $html .= '<h2>' . strtoupper($category->name) . ' KEYBINDS</h2>';
    }
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'category-keybinds', 'shortcode_post_category' );
```

From what I understand I need to change the `get_the_categories` to `get_the_term`(?) however with my very limited knowledge of `php` I cannot seem to get this to work on the new "game" taxonomy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code of [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) you see that this is not much more than a call to `get_the_terms ( $id, 'category' )`, where `$id` is the current post id.

So, what you need is `get_the_terms ( get_the_ID(), 'game' )`. You need `get_the_ID`, because the `ID` is not passed to the shortcode as it is to `get_the_category`.

Comment: You're a star. Thanks for the help, it's worked great.